# Show/hide div on scroll from ID to ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to show a fixed div when i scroll onto and ID and then hide it when it gets to another ID or when a i scroll back to top and pass by the ID that had triggered it.
At the moment my code is showing the div in the ID i want and it's hidding when i scroll back to top at the same ID position but im not beeing able to also hide it when the next ID appears.

This is a small example of my code

https://jsfiddle.net/wo45r3yv/2/

I want to show the .cscroll div on scroll down at id="show" and then on scroll top hide it again on id="show" (that's working), when it reaches id="last-div" i want it to disappear again but also to appear on scroll top when reaches the bottom of id=middle-div, basicly the main idea is to have the fixed bar appearing on id="middle-div" but trigered by div ID and not screen position

Hope someone can help me

Many thanks

```js
var offsetTop = $("#show").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > offsetTop){
    $(".sticky-section").slideDown('200');
    $(".cscroll").fadeIn('200');
  }
  else {
        $(".sticky-section").slideUp('200');
        $(".cscroll").fadeOut('200');
}
});
```

```css
#first-div {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}

#middle-div {
  height: 1600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#last-div {
  height: 2600px;
  background-color: green;
}

.cscroll {
  width : 100%;
}

.sticky-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.32);

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="first-div">
  MASTER
</div>

<div id="show"></div>
<div class="cscroll sticky-section">
    <h4>
        sticky content headline
    </h4>
    <h5>
        more texts
    </h5>
</div>


<div id="middle-div">
 NEW DIV
</div>


<div id="last-div">
  LAST DIV
</div>
```

Comment: Have you investigated IntersectionObserver?

Comment: Just looked at it now but without success. I've tried a lot of things to have this working but no luck =(

Comment: Could you show us what you tried with IntersectionObserver so we can help as it really should be useful as it will trigger on an element ('on an id' as you put it) coming and going on scroll rather than needing to know scroll positions.

Comment: I have writen this code that on fiddle is not working but on my local project is working and almost doing what i need:
https://jsfiddle.net/g63vxsq4/1/
If you could help it will be amazing